# DataStax Enterprise Migration to 3.1: Solr Schema Parsing Failed: Invalid field property

Tags: solr, datastax-enterprise

After upgrading to DSE 3.1.1 posting a previously working schema.xml and solrconfig.xml and creating the core we got an exception like this:

```
<lst name="responseHeader">
  <int name="status">500</int>
  <int name="QTime">303</int>
</lst>
<lst name="error">
  <str name="msg">Schema Parsing Failed: Invalid field property: positionIncrementGap</str>
  <str name="trace">org.apache.solr.common.SolrException: Schema Parsing Failed: Invalid field property: positionIncrementGap
at org.apache.solr.schema.IndexSchema.readSchema(IndexSchema.java:687)
at com.datastax.bdp.cassandra.index.solr.CassandraIndexSchema.readSchema(CassandraIndexSchema.java:48)
...
```

Original post: http://www.datastax.com/support-forums/topic/dse-migration-30311-solr-schema-parsing-failed-invalid-field-property-positionincrementgap

Answer (score 3, accepted):

DSE 3.1 upgraded to Solr 4.3, which includes better schema validation. In other words in older releases of Solr unacceptable attributes were silently ignored while now they are fatal errors.

In this particular case, the positionIncrementGap attribute belongs on the fieldType rather than the field.But more generally, you should take a close look at your schema.

Thanks to Jack for the original answer.

Sven